# Mapa do Google Maps não abre depois do app lançado

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps

Estou usando o Google Maps Android API, porém não está funcionando quando envio o app para o Google Play. No debug funciona normalmente e quando executo o aplicativo pelo Android Studio também, mas quando lanço o aplicativo para o Playstore ele não abre os mapas no qual faço as solicitações. Subi ontem o app, e lá nas estatísticas do google console até mostra que foi feito solicitação (veja a imagem abaixo), no entanto, aparentemente não abriu o map.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém já se deparou com esta situação?

Comment: O seu celular esta com o modo developer ativado? Pois creio que se estiver poderá conectar com o PC/Maquina e usar o depurado do ADT mesmo no App baixado pela playstore, não lembro se precisa de *root*.

Answer (score 1):

Cleidimar,

Você precisa criar a HASH Key de Release, provavelmente você só criou a debug.

Ai você troca lá o ip que a hash retorna, e fica com dois, um de desenvolvimento e um de produção.

Abraços.

Comment: Fala Leonardo, blz?! A princípio, valeu ai por ajudar. Bom, eu já tinha criado a hash de release, usando a keystore com extensão .jks. Agora não qual é esse ip que você está falando. Eu uso exatamente a chave que foi gerada a partir do sha1 gerado com essa hash de release. Será que ainda falta alguma coisa?

Comment: Estou usando assim para gerar meu sha1

keytool -list -v -alias minhachave -keystore 'D:\Dropbox\minhachave.jks'

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava com esse problema e consegui resolver. Só precisei abrir AndroidMainifest e mudar a parte onde é solicitado o API Key do maps. Ao invés de indicar a chave usando string, digitei a chave direto. Ficou assim:
Antes:

```
<meta-data-->
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Depois:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="digitei a API KEY aqui" />
```